# Workflows not running after SharePoint enabled with SSL

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, workflow-manager, ssl

I had SharePoint 2013 SPD Workflows successfully running on SharePoint 2016 Enterprise Server but recently after enabling the web application with SSL certificate, workflows stop executing. I tried this on 3 different servers, each one throwing different kind of errors. Tried with ULS but did not found any helpful cause of error. Do I need to do any additional configuration at Workflow Manager side to make this working? Or the below article is the solution to my problem?

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-workflow-manager-certificates-in-sharepoint-server

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to re register the Workflow Manager proxy on SharePoint server side as your web application using the SSL while you register workflow proxy with http.

```
Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://myserver/mysitecollection" -WorkflowHostUri "https://workflow.example.com:12290" -force
```

Check this: [Install and configure workflow for SharePoint Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/governance/install-and-configure-workflow-for-sharepoint-server)

Comment: Yes I ran the above command but still no luck. Workflows are still not running. Do I need to do any additional steps?

Comment: what error you are seeing in the logs? also make sure Service bus services running on the WFM server

Comment: All services are running, I verified in CA and through PowerShell using Get-SBFarmStatus and Get-WFFarmStatus commands.

Comment: In workflow history list I am seeing this error log for every workflow instance -
"System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult) at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Microsoft.Workflow.Common.AsyncResult.End[TAs"

Comment: Do we need create a trusted valid certificate for Workflow Manager site in IIS or Workflow Manager service creates a certificate on own and assigns itself? I feel like this all issue is occurring due to certificates. Also followed below this article to troubleshoot but still same issue - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/resolving-invalid-remote-certificate-error-in-sharepoint-workflow-manager/

Comment: you have to configure ur Workflow manager using SSL, then re register it using the register command....you also need to add the WFM certificate into the SharePoint...via central admin > security manage trust

Comment: how can I configure my workflow manager using SSL? Do i need to generate any SSL certificates similar to what I did for my SharePoint web application?

Comment: What i beleive, you configured the WFM farm using the http but now want to use https.if you check the workflowmanager site in IIS, i am sure no binding for 12290 port...what i will do in this sitution, re configure the Workflow Manager farm using the https then join it to the sharepoint to avoid any issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to the above problem was:

1. Uninstalled all Workflow Manager and Service Bus Cumulative Updates.
2. Uninstalled Workflow Manager
3. Re-installed Workflow Manager.
4. Attached Trusted Signed SSL Certificate for Workflow Manager (This time I did not use self-signed certificate)
5. Register the Workflow Service in SharePoint 2016 Management Shell

Register-SPWorkflowService -SPSite "https://myserver/mysitecollection"
-WorkflowHostUri "https://workflow.example.com:12290"

6. Opened SPD 2013 workflows in SharePoint Designer 2013 and re-published each workflow.

The workflows were not visible at first in SharePoint Designer 2013 as we had migrated DB from UAT to production. After installing SPD Service Pack 1 and 8th April 2018 hotfix, workflows were visible in SPD for re-publish.

The key points here is to re-install Workflow Manager and used a trusted signed SSL certificate for Workflow Manager and also for SharePoint web application and finally re-publishing the workflows.